# I am getting an error while fetching data in react native with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Here is the API link:

http://muslimsalat.com/london/true/5.json

```
<Text>Query: {responseMsg.query}</Text>
<Text>For: {responseMsg.for}</Text>
<Text>Prayer Method: {responseMsg.prayer_method_name}</Text>
<Text>Daylight: {responseMsg.daylight}</Text>
```

The above lines are working.

I am able to fetch data from this API like, query, for, daylight, city, country and more, but I am unable to fetch prayer times from this API. I don't know how to write that line to fetch prayer times from this API.

`<Text>Times: {responseMsg.items.fajr}</Text>`
The above line is not working. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`responseMsg.items` is an array. Use map to get times:

```
<Text>Times: {(responseMsg.items || []).map(item => item.fajr).join(',')}</Text>
```

Comment: this is also not working.. undefined is not an object (evaluating 'responseMsg.items.map')

Comment: `responseMsg.items` must be `undefined` in that case, map can only be applied to an array not to `undefined`, you should put a safe check like `(responseMsg.items || []).map(item => item.fajr).join(',')`